# Catching not-my-code exception, and not leaving the execution flow

Tags: python, exception

I have the following code:

```
import x
try:
    1. do a
    2. execute x.do
    3. do c
except x.fail:
    handle x.failure
```

While 2 fails on exception it will do to the exception code at the end. I want to have a separate (even on thread) handler for this exception so it will handle the failure and continue executing "3. do c"

Is there a proper solution beside creating a function

that will execute x.do and will catch inside the function?

Comment: Why can't you just start the try block before 2 and catch it just after 2, leaving 3  outside of the try block?

Comment: Well I don't want to fill the code with try. I use device object: device(xpath='s/s/x/x') and device's class is not my class